# Java to read different database tables

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I try to receive content of tables using Java code. This is the basic code and I have an issue with it. I need the code to be flexible so it can read different tables (with different amount of rows/columns etc). I want the while loop to print all the columns in a particular table.

```
public class Main1 {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql:address", "root", "");

        String SQL = "select * from users";
        ResultSet rs = Statement.executeQuery();
          ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
          System.out.println("querying SELECT * FROM users");
          int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
          while (rs.next()) {
              for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
                  if (i > 1) System.out.print(",  ");
                  String columnValue = rs.getString(i);
                  System.out.print(columnValue + " " + rsmd.getColumnName(i));
              }
              System.out.println("");
          }

        }
      }
```

Comment: so what is going wrong?  Going to give up my job as a mind-reader, I am just no good at it

Comment: haha sorry I didn't specify the issues. The line "ResultSet rs = Statement.executeQuery();" is apparently incorrect. Then, I'm questioning if there is some better and more efficient way to do what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, you are probably better off using a `PreparedStatement`

consider

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement (SQL);
rs = ps.executeQuery ();
```

Comment: Works great! I wrote the rest but then there is one issue. "String SQL = "select * from" +tablename;" (where tablename) is a string given by the user in the command line. This is outside the quote and doesn't work correctly. I need to be able to select the table therefore, I need to be able to select the table this way.